# Python3 f.write UnicodeEncodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't encode characters surrogates not allowed

Tags: python, file, encoding, cjk

Run Python files over the web (php).
Afterwards, an error occurs while printing the Korean string to a file with Python.
On the other hand, running Python files directly using the terminal does not cause errors.
Do you know what the problem is?
Please help me.

```
error Traceback (most recent call last): File "makeApp.py", line 171, 
in modify_app_info(app_name) File "makeApp.py", line 65, in modify_app_info f.write(line+"\n") UnicodeEncodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't encode characters in position 13-30: surrogates not allowed
```

Below is the code that causes the problem.

```
    lines = read_file(read_file_path)

    f = open(read_file_path, 'r', encoding='UTF-8')
    lines = f.readlines()
    f.close()
    
    f = open(write_file_path, 'w', encoding='UTF-8')
    for line in lines:
        if '"name": "userInputAppName"' in line:
            line = '    "name": "' + app_name + '",')
            continue
        f.write(line+"\n")
        # f.write(line)
    f.close()
```

Answer (score -1):

**Remove the **encoding** param, cauz you open a file in encoded mode so, you can't join any *substring* on the string.**
So your code will be--

```py
# ...
    lines = read_file(read_file_path)

    f = open(read_file_path, 'r')
    lines = f.readlines()
    f.close()
    
    f = open(write_file_path, 'w')
    for line in lines:
        if '"name": "userInputAppName"' in line:
            line = '    "name": "' + app_name + '",')
            continue
        f.write(line+"\n")
        # f.write(line)
    f.close()
```

Comment: `you open a file in encoded mode` there's no such mode. Reading text from a file *always* uses an encoding, either the default or the one specified by the parameter. Depending on the system settings, the default is already UTF8.